# How do I change the length of the bone?

Tags: armature, bones, axis

I'm planning on making multiple bones for each finger but I want to change the length for each of them while still keeping the angle intact. How do I do that?[image]

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode? Change the Transform Orientation to Normal

[image: Transform Orientation]

Then select the end of the bone, grab it (press <kbd>G</kbd>), restrict to the Y axis (press <kbd>Y</kbd>), and drag to the length you want.

Setting the Transform Orientation to Normal makes it use the bone's Y axis when you press <kbd>Y</kbd> (which is the direction the bone points) instead of the global Y axis.